# powershell - how to Get-Date

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, getdate

I have the following

```
foreach($res in $result1)
    {
        $ed = $res.EVENT_DATE
    }
```

`$ed` is

> 29 September 2015 00:00:00

(It comes out of a MySQL Database as '2015-09-29' - but I'm assuming powershell is being 'clever' and converting it).

However, I need it to display as '

> 2015-09-27

I tried:

```
$ed = $res.EVENT_DATE
$ed = get-date -date $ed
```

With the intention of then formatting it accordingly, But this gives me

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. 
Exception setting "Date": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

What is the correct way of formatting this to display as required?

Comment: Why would you want a date of 29 September to display as 27 September? What do you get for $ed.GetType().

Comment: Also, this: (get-date '29 September 2015 00:00:00').ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')  results in: 2015-09-29 for me so I think you have something else going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How Powershell displays it depends on your locale info.
For example:

```
D:\> get-date "29 September 2015 00:00:00"

Tuesday, September 29, 2015 12:00:00 AM

D:\> get-date "29 September 2015 00:00:00" -Format yyyy-MM-dd
2015-09-29
```

so you might try this:

```
foreach($res in $result1)
    {
        $ed = get-date $res.EVENT_DATE -format yyyy-MM-dd
    }
```

Comment: cheers, you are quite right. It seems I misread the documentation, and I don't need the `-date` switch.